# Query Improvement mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hi Guys i have this query and it is super slow.
If you can understand the code how can i possibly combine the two queries into one
or how can i possibly make this query faster.

this is the code

```
$strSQL  = "SELECT user_status_history.*, queues_config.extension FROM user_status_history ";
    $strSQL .= "LEFT JOIN queues_config ON user_status_history.skillset = REPLACE(queues_config.grppre, \":\", \"\") ";
    $strSQL .= "WHERE user_status_history.status_id = 9 "; # outbound call
    $strSQL .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(status_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$check_date' ";
    if ($i==1)
        $strSQL .= "AND TIME_FORMAT(status_time, '%H:%i') >= '$cboHrFrom:$cboMinFrom' ";
    else if (strtotime($check_date) == strtotime($end_date))
        $strSQL .= "AND TIME_FORMAT(status_time, '%H:%i') <= '$cboHrTo:$cboMinTo' ";
    $strSQL .= "AND queues_config.extension = '$cboSkillSet' ";
    if ($cboGroup!='' && $strAgentGroup!='') $strSQL .= "AND user_status_history.user_id IN (".$strAgentGroup.") ";
    $strSQL .= "ORDER BY user_status_history.user_id, user_status_history.status_time ";
    $rs2     = &$cn->Execute($strSQL);
    while (!$rs2->EOF)
    {
        $strSQL  = "SELECT status_time, time_to_sec(timediff(status_time, '".$rs2->fields['status_time']."')) AS timesecs FROM user_status_history ";
        $strSQL .= "LEFT JOIN queues_config ON user_status_history.skillset = REPLACE(queues_config.grppre, \":\", \"\") ";
        $strSQL .= "WHERE status_time > '".$rs2->fields['status_time']."' ";
        $strSQL .= "AND user_id = '".$rs2->fields['user_id']."' ";
        $strSQL .= "AND queues_config.extension = '".$rs2->fields['extension']."' ";
        $strSQL .= "ORDER BY status_time LIMIT 1;";
        $rs3     = &$cn->Execute($strSQL);
        if (!$rs3->EOF)
        {
            $sum_talk_sec = $sum_talk_sec + $rs3->fields['timesecs'];
        }
        $rs3->Close();

        $rs2->MoveNext();
    }
    $rs2->Close();
```

Comment: Lest we forget about [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/)...

Comment: 0) Show your CREATE TABLE and EXPLAIN statements. 1) You don't have *a query*, you have *N+1 queries*, from the looks of things you can rewrite it as a JOIN aggregate. 2) WHERE clauses like `DATE_FORMAT(column, format) = 'expression'` cannot be indexed and require a slow full scan.

Comment: @DCoder IMHO JOIN is good when it limits the result set. In this case it only adds new information and should be a separate query.  The point about DATE_FORMAT is good. I have to add that one to my own.

Comment: @anttir: when you use a JOIN, the query optimizer has a better understanding of what you want than when you give it an arbitrary IN(...) condition.

Comment: @anttir - "JOIN is good when it limits the result set" Really? That sounds insane to me.

Comment: Please post just the queries and get rid of all this PHP noise if you want query help. It makes it really hard to read and optimize. If you have multiple (types of) queries, then simply post all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1

Check out there are table indexes for

user_status_history.status_id

user_status_history.user_id

## 2

these are difficult for optimizer. Try get rid of these

```
LEFT JOIN queues_config ON user_status_history.skillset = REPLACE(queues_config.grppre, \":\", \"\") ";
LEFT JOIN queues_config ON user_status_history.skillset = REPLACE(queues_config.grppre, \":\", \"\") ";
```

## 3

Get rid of the loop query.
Fetch all IDs from query1 to an array and create one query for them all:

"SELECT user_id, status_time, time_to_sec(timediff(status_time, '".$rs2->fields['status_time']."')) AS timesecs FROM user_status_history ";
 ...
AND user_id IN (id1, id2, id3 ... )

## 4  (From  DCOder )

Convert these the other way around. Use PHP to create mysql datetime fields.

```
    $strSQL .= "AND DATE_FORMAT(status_time, '%Y-%m-%d') = '$check_date' ";

-- > 
    preg_match('/^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])$/', $check_date, $regs );
    $enddate = date('Y-m-d', mktime( $hour=6, $min=0, $sec=0, $mon=$regs[2], $day=$regs[3]+1, $year=$regs[1] ));
    $strSQL .= " AND status_time > '$check_date' AND status_time <= '$enddate' ; 


    $strSQL .= "AND TIME_FORMAT(status_time, '%H:%i') >= '$cboHrFrom:$cboMinFrom' ";

-- >  $strSQL .= " AND status_time >= '$check_date $cboHrFrom:$cboMinFrom:00' ";

    $strSQL .= "AND TIME_FORMAT(status_time, '%H:%i') <= '$cboHrTo:$cboMinTo' ";

-- >  $strSQL .= " AND status_time <= '$check_date $cboHrTo:$cboMinTo:59' ";
```

Comment: Hi all, I'll try to work on what you have said. Thank you all for your help.